# Пространства имен PHP

Tags: php, namespace

У меня есть такая строка в скрипте:
use PayPal\Service\AdaptivePaymentsService;

Она подключает класс. Как узнать путь к этому классу, который подключается данной строкой ?

Answer (score 1):

Должна быть папка с названием *PayPal*, далее папка *Service* и файл *AdaptivePaymentsService*. Большинство PHP-редакторов позволяют перейти в нужный файл при нажатии `Ctrl + {названия класса}`.

Answer (score 0):

Ну эта строка не подключает класс, а всего лишь объявляет псевдоним для этого класса, а сам класс может даже не используется если его не вызывать. Искать его нужно там, где написал regent.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, как устроен у вас автозагрузчик: в каких папках ищет классы.

Или можно сделать как-то так:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass("AdaptivePaymentsService");
$fn = $reflector->getFileName();
echo "Класс находится в папке: " . dirname($fn);
```